# Pass function negative as n argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, metaprogramming

In Python I can pass a function as a parameter to another function, i.e.:

```
inspect.getmembers(random, callable)
```

It would get me all the callable members of a `random` variable. And `callable` is a function passed to perform the check (only members of variable satisfying the check would be returned).

My particular question is how to get all not callable arguments, and more broadly is there a way to pass the "reverse" of a function as an argument?

I have tried this:

```
inspect.getmembers(random, !callable)
inspect.getmembers(random, not callable)
```

And the first is a syntax error, while the second does not work.

As a workaround I have defined my own function:

```
def uncallable(object)
    return not callable(object)
```

And so this works:

```
inspect.getmembers(random, uncallable)
```

But I wonder if there's an easier solution.

Comment: "Easier" than just writing that function? How many predicates do you need? (Not entirely rhetorical; it's worth thinking about this.)

Comment: You can use an anonymous function: `inspect.getmembers(random, lambda x: not callable(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a lambda:

```
inspect.getmembers(random, lambda x: not callable(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write your uncallable wrapper.

No language I am aware of allows the kind of high level function arithmetic you expect.

There is no way to make such a concept work in general.

What is the resulting function of these: ?

```
! len
len + len
len + ! len
```

So what we're left with are explicitly written high order functions, akka functions that take functions as parameters and return other functions like this

```
def negate(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return not func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

uncallable = negate(callable)
```

These is the same pattern as python decorators.